how to adjust the position of the viewpager when opening the application
How do I display the initial position of the viewpager as desired when opening an application, such as TikTok?
Example my application
expected example, can open the page as desired
I'm confused about adjusting it. I need the source code to solve this problem.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
